# Standard SQL - not able to pull actual UTC time in days/hours

Tags: sql, timestamp, utc

I am having trouble pulling the below data in actual UTC time. I would like the day, hour, and ticket count but for some reason it does not seem to be pulling in UTC (data doesn't make sense). It is also pulling a few hours of 7-15 and only goes as far as 8-25

Does it have to do with a setting that I'm not aware of? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Query below:

SET timezone "UTC";

```
SELECT
  day,
  CONCAT(cast(hour as STRING),':00') as hour,   
  COUNT(DISTINCT units) as count

FROM
  tableABC
WHERE
  created.timestamp BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2018-07-16 00:00:00 UTC") 
  AND TIMESTAMP("2018-08-26 00:00:00 UTC")
```

Comment: your dbms name please

Comment: "only goes as far as 8-25" - that would (generally) be expected. `2018-08-26 00:00:00 UTC` defines midnight at the start of 8-26. And that's the endpoint for your range. Anything that happened *during* 8-26 (and didn't happen at precisely midnight) comes after that point in time.

Comment: "It is also pulling a few hours of 7-15" - the data in the table is likely not in UTC, so by querying it in UTC it's very well possible that some rows created east of Greenwich will show up.

Comment: @SQLearner . . . .Please tag your questions with the database you are using.

Comment: Ah got it thanks for the tip. Bigquery it was

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d',timestamp, "UTC") as day,
  CONCAT(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%H',timestamp, "UTC"),':00') as hour,

Thank you Zaynul.

dbms was bigquery